# Asp.net core 5 Odata error ( services.AddOData; not working)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

```cs
services.AddOData();
services.AddRouting();
services.AddCors(...);
```

> CS1920: 'IServiceContainer' does not contain a definition for 'AddOData' and thebest extension method overload 'ODataMvcBuilderExtensions.AddOData(IMvcBuilder)' requires a receiver of type 'IMvcBuilder'

I installed all packages needed here is the list of the packages in my project

[image: packages]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not image.

Comment: Post the code and the *full* exception or error text as *text*, not images. Images can't be compiled or googled

Comment: Also the *actual* packages and versions you used. The ASP.NET Core OData v8 package added a *lot* of changes but little documentation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommended way of setting up OData services has changed as of v8 to an extension method on `IMvcBuilder` returned by `AddControllers()`

```cs
sservices.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => opt.Count().Filter().Expand().Select().OrderBy().SetMaxTop(5)/* other config */);
```

See [the docs](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData#2-basic-usage) for further info.

Comment: Calling this `docs` is .... an euphemism. I admire your restrain. Working with the 8 RC over the last few months, the constant *breaking* changes in routing even in the RC versions was ..... The real documentation at this point are the repo examples.

Comment: And then I found out that while `$apply` works, ASP.NET Core OData won't translate it to an EF GroupBy query ....

Comment: I always refer to the tests for the most correct usage. Docs might be lagging behind, but tests are usually up-to-date.

Comment: Came looking for the same thing. There are still multiple MS blog posts with the wrong sample code. Thanks for supplying the correct info

Comment: You can also do services.AddMvc().AddOData()